# How do you set and retrieve an instance of BookshelfJS using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to use [Bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org/) along with [Express 4.0](http://expressjs.com/) and can't seem to get them working together or rather, I can't seem to follow "best practices". The Bookshelf docs mention that one should always reuse the same instance of it throughout the app. It even lists an example:

```
// When the app starts
var app = express();
var knex = require('knex')(dbConfig);
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

app.set('bookshelf', bookshelf);

// elsewhere, to use the bookshelf client:
var bookshelf = app.get('bookshelf');

var Post = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  // ...
});
```

However, I can't seem to get it working when I have to use `app.get()` in a separate file. For example, here's my `app.js` file (the root of my entire app):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var db = require('./server/db/db');
app.set('bookshelf', db);

var api = require('./server');

app.use(api);
```

Here's my `db.js` file that gets required above:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var knex = require('knex')({ //my db settings go here });
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

module.exports = bookshelf;
```

The above code works if I require it directly. Here's where the issue turns up. Whenever I want to actually use the bookshelf connection, no matter what file I'm in, I follow the same process but it fails and "bookshelf" is always undefined. Here's an example of an `index.js` file that's required and called "api" in the `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var db = app.get('bookshelf');
console.log(db);
```

DB *always* comes up as undefined. Whenever I try to make a new Model, I use the same process except I do an `db.Model.extend({})` and trying to access the `Model` property throws an error (because it's undefined).

From what I can use both Bookshelf and Express docs agree that this should work and it doesn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line creates a new app every time you call it:

```
var myApp = express();
```

If you want to set or get variables from the same app, you'll have to pass it as an argument.

```
var api = require('./server')(myApp);
```

And then in your api module:

```
module.exports = function(app){
    var db = app.get('bookshelf');
//....
};
```

On a side note: you don't have to worry about singletons in Node.js all you have to do is just require it.

```
var db = require('./path/to/db/config');
```

It'll only be instantiated once and cached for later calls.

Comment: Ahh, wonderful. That explains why some of the other codebases didn't bother with anything elaborate and just required it instead.